# If else in react.js(basic)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, if-statement, spotify

I am building a simple single page app on react.js for the first time using spotifys api keys. Ive managed to get the song info on the page when a user is playing a song. How can I add an else statement to this so that I have something like "No Playback deteced" appear when nothing is playing?

```
{ (() => {
          if (this.state.nowPlaying.id) {

            return (
              <div>
                <div> Now Playing: { this.state.nowPlaying.name} </div>
                <div> By: { this.state.nowPlaying.artist} </div>
                <div> Id: { this.state.nowPlaying.id} </div>
                <div> Progress: { this.state.nowPlaying.progress} </div>
                <div>
                  <img src={ this.state.nowPlaying.image} style={{ width: 100}}/>
                </div>
                <AudioFeatures
                 id={this.state.nowPlaying.id}
                 ref={this.audioFeatures}
                 oAuth={this.state.oAuth}
                />
              </div>
            );
          } 
        }

        })()
      }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try using ternary operator like, ```{this.state.nowPlaying.id ? return (<div>  Your existing if statement logic  </div>) : <div > No Playback deteced </div>}``` ..

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) in the React documentation talks about various options for conditional rendering.

Where possible, I prefer doing the conditional part before the JSX expression I'm going to embed it in, but if you want it embedded in that expression, you can use the conditional operator (covered on that page [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator)) rather than creating and running a temporary arrow function:

```
{ this.state.nowPlaying && this.state.nowPlaying.id
  ?      <div>
          <div> Now Playing: { this.state.nowPlaying.name} </div>
          <div> By: { this.state.nowPlaying.artist} </div>
          <div> Id: { this.state.nowPlaying.id} </div>
          <div> Progress: { this.state.nowPlaying.progress} </div>
          <div>
            <img src={ this.state.nowPlaying.image} style={{ width: 100}}/>
          </div>
          <AudioFeatures
           id={this.state.nowPlaying.id}
           ref={this.audioFeatures}
           oAuth={this.state.oAuth}
          />
        </div>
  :     <div>No Playback detected</div>
}
```

But again, I would do it before that JSX expression to simplify things:

```
let nowPlaying;
if (this.state.nowPlaying && this.state.nowPlaying.id) {
    newPlaying = <div>
     <div> Now Playing: { this.state.nowPlaying.name} </div>
     <div> By: { this.state.nowPlaying.artist} </div>
     <div> Id: { this.state.nowPlaying.id} </div>
     <div> Progress: { this.state.nowPlaying.progress} </div>
     <div>
       <img src={ this.state.nowPlaying.image} style={{ width: 100}}/>
     </div>
     <AudioFeatures
      id={this.state.nowPlaying.id}
      ref={this.audioFeatures}
      oAuth={this.state.oAuth}
     />
    </div>;
} else {
    nowPlaying = <div>No Playback detected</div>;
}
```

then in your JSX expression:

```
{nowPlaying}
```